# Is "cumbers" a word?

Tags: verbs

I'm looking for a slogan for my new website (https://numbr.dev, online calculator with support for currencies).

And thought of this slogan:

```
Numbers are no
longer cumbers.
```

Does it make sense? And is "cumber" a word?

Thanks!

Comment: Google `define cumber`

Comment: "If numbers make you go numb, Numbr will make you go 'yumb!'"

Comment: _And is "cumber" a word?_, what were you hoping it meant?

Comment: I looked in a few dictionaries, yes. But do you understand it?

Comment: The term 'archaic' and 'dated' that you see in all the definitions means that few would recognize it as a word much less have any hint at what it might mean

Comment: *Does it make sense?* Yes, but it should be on one line. *And is "cumber" a word?* Yes - not common, but most people will understand.

Comment: *number sums made less cumbersome*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling, I see:

> **cum·ber**
>
> verb DATED
> hamper or hinder (someone or something).
> *they were cumbered with greatcoats and swords*
>
> noun ARCHAIC
> a hindrance, obstruction, or burden.
> *a cumber of limestone rocks* [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=cumber&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&oq=cumber&aqs=chrome..69i57j46i433i512j46i175i199i433i512l3j69i60l3.976j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

and

> **cumber** transitive verb
>
> 1 archaic : TROUBLE, HARASS
>
> 2a: to hinder or encumber by being in the way
> *cumbered with heavy clothing*
>
> b: to clutter up
> *rocks cumbering the yard*
>
> **cumber** noun
> something that  cumbers
> *especially*: HINDRANCE [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cumber)

I agree that "Numbers are no longer an encumbrance" won't work in a jingle.